# How do I import facebook friends from the another website

Tags: facebook

I am looking for a way to connect to facebook by allowing the user to enter in their username and password and have our app connect to their account and get their contacts so that they can invite them to join their group on our site. I have written a facebook app before, but this is not an app as much as it is a connector so that they can invite all their friends or just some to the site we are working on.

I have seen several other sites do this and also connect to Yahoo, Gmail and Hotmail contacts. I dont think they are using Facebook Connect to do this since it is so new, but they may be.

Any solution in any language is fine as I can port whatever example to use C#. I cannot find anything specifically on Google or Facebook to address this specific problem. Any help is appreciated.

I saw a first answer get removed that had suggested i might need to scrape the friends page. The more I look around, this might be what i need to do. Any other way i think will require the person to add it as an app. I am wondering how a answer can get removed, maybe that user deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

[Try This](http://creators.ning.com/forum/topics/how-to-import-facebook-friends)

Not sure if its possible explicitly but there are indirect ways to do it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another article that seems to cover what you want to do http://facebook-developer.net/2008/02/20/allow-your-users-to-invite-their-friends/